# Enumerator as ctypes argument in Python

Tags: python, dll, enums, ctypes

There are functions for controlling a device in a DLL, which I am accessing via Python with ctypes. However, the C function being called in Python uses an input (PmcaDeviceType) that I don't understand how to implement. The manufacturer defines the function as:

> C declaration: `int PmcaAsyncConnect(int * result, int port, int baudRate, PmcaDeviceType device);`

And the manufacturer lists the PmcaDeviceType as an enumerator that can have one of three possible values (its C code shown below):

```
typedef enum
{
    PMCA_AUTO_DETECT,
    PMCA_8000,
    PMCA_8000A
} PmcaDevicetype;
```

To attempt to call the function, I'm using the following code:

```
import ctypes
from enum import Enum

class PmcaDeviceType(Enum):
    PMCA_AUTO_DETECT = 0
    PMCA_8000 = 1
    PMCA_8000A = 2

PMCAfns = ctypes.dll.LoadLibrary(DLLfile)
Connect = PMCAfns.PmcaAsyncConnect
Connect.restype = ctypes.c_int
Connect.argtypes  = [ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_char_p]
Connect(1,1200,PmcaDeviceType.PMCA_8000A)
```

But I'm met with the error message:

> argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

I think the issue is in how I am inputting the device type argument, but I do not know how to go about correctly doing so. I am new to C and Python, so I appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: `.argtypes` doesn’t match the function definition

Answer (score 0):

Your dll is expecting an integer, but you are passing in an enum object.  For cases like these you need to combine Enum with the target value.  So either roll your own:

```
class PmcaDeviceType(int, Enum):
    etc.
```

or use the one that comes with Python:

```
class PmcaDeviceType(IntEnum):
    etc.
```

I would recommend using `IntEnum`.

---

What's the difference?

In Python 3.11 `IntEnum` will have its `str()` output changed to match the inherent data type, so only its `repr()` will be different:

```
>>> str(PmcaDeviceType.PMCA_8000)
1  # instead of PmcaDeviceType.PMCA_8000
```